# No Jsp Editor with Eclipse Galileo 3.3

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor, eclipse-wtp

I just installed Eclipse Galileo, but have no JSP editor.

In file associations, on the Preferences page, *.jsp was not even mentioned.

When I added it and went to associate with the built-in Jsp Editor, there was none in the list.

Note: I have WTP 3.1.1 installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes - Galileo is the 3.5 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What JVM are you using? 1.5 or 6 is necessary for WTP to run properly.
Can you activate a Java EE perspective, which would then give you access to all those features (JSP editor, JSP file association, and so on)

If all that fails, you can always try a parallel clean installation of the **[Java EE edition of Galileo eclipse 3.5.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages)**, which should have everything running out of the box.

Comment: thanks .. there are two Galileo downloads for Java, one of them being the EE edition. The other edition (which I installed) does not mention a JSP editor. The EE edition does mention support for JSF, so I'm guessing that's where the JSP functionality lies.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be resolved by installing Eclipse Java EE version. Else you need to install the following tool to get jsp context menu under New.

Go to **Help->Install New Software** and install the item **"Web Page Editor (Optional)" under Web,XML, and Java EE Development**